# Count from hasManyThrough relationship with eager loading (need only Count)

Tags: laravel, count, eloquent, has-many-through, eager-loading

## I only need the count, don't want to retrive the results or perform query each time for each row. This is why I want eager loading.

I have 3 tables like the following:

```
Admins
    id

Posts
    id
    admin_id

Comments
    id
    user_id    //nullable (null if comment from admin)
    admin_id   //nullable (null if comment from user)
    news_id
```

Now I want to retrieve all the posts from a single admin and all the comments count from those posts, without retrieving all the comments for posts, ONLY COUNT of comments,
With eager loading to avoid n+1 query issue;

Here I think we should make a relation to be used with eager loading like the following:

```
//admin model    
public function commentsCountRelation()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough(Comment::class, News::class, 'admin_id', 'news_id')
                ->selectRaw('news_id, count(*) as count')
                ->groupBy('news_id');
            
        }
```

--Look Here I used `hasManyThrough` relation because, news_id is not in `Admins` table.

Then I should make an attribute, to access the count easyly, like:

```
public function getCommentsCountAttribute()
    {   
        return $this->commentsCountRelation->first()->count ?? 0;
    }
```

Then access it like:

```
$admin = Admin::with('commentsCountRelation')->findOrFail($id);
$admin->commentsCount;
```

But it always returns `null`, why is that?

The following works for `hasMany` & `belongsTo`, I've used it on my other models like:

```
//relation
public function ordersCountRelation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Order::class)->selectRaw('user_id, count(*) as count')
            ->groupBy('user_id');
        
    }

//attribute
public function getOrdersCountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->ordersCountRelation->count ?? 0;
    }

//Then accessed like:
$user = User::with('ordersCountRelation')->find($id);
$user->ordersCount; //return only count
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for using `hasManyThrough`.
just use some relations and `withCount` method:

`$admin->posts->withCount('comments')->get();`

then you can access it with: `$comments_count`

Comment: I didn't understand. The app has multiple admin & all of them has posts. Now I need all posts from specific admin & all the comments count for ONLY those posts, 
In question I described table structure & I need that comment count while I'm working with `Admin` model, 

Can you please explain me how do I do that without `hasManyThrough` as I don't want to get counts for all posts but only posts from this admin.

I need that like this (after looping) `$admin->post->commentCount`

I will highly appreciate if you give me some code example or explain in brief

Comment: Relations: `Admin` has `hasMany` with `Post` has `hasMany` with `Comment`

Comment: I also think your method is not using eager loading, does it?
Also can you please tell me what is the efficiency benefit using your mention method instead of `$admin->post->comments->count()`